# Check if another event is fired from an event handler function

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Let's imagine I have an event handler function attached to an image, for example, an `onmouseover` handler. I don't want this handler run if an `onmouseover` event is fired by a particular element.

To be more specific, I have an image which being hovered, a menu is popped out. I want to close that menu if the mouse moves out of that image, unless I move the mouse to the menu, which is adjacent to the image.

So something like this in pseudo code:

```
img.mouseout = function () {
if (otherelement.onmouseover.fired) {
 leave the menu as it is
} 
else 
{
close the menu
}
```

So how can I check whether another event was fired?

Comment: You'd have to keep track of it yourself, and that will be complicated by the tenuous control you have over the order in which the event handlers are called.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a timeout and a mouseover handler that clears it in the other handler. While the elements could be exactly next to each other visually, adding a small timer is more safe since there might just be a tiny 1px area where the mouseout event fires, causing an ugly flickering.

This also allows a quick mouseshake without flicker.

Something like:

```
var timer;

img.onmouseout = other.onmouseout = function() {
  timer = setTimeout(closemenu, 100);
}

img.onmouseover = other.onmouseover = function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

function closemenu() {
  // close it
}
```